# Firebase google cloud functions - Download File - Not Found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do the thumb generator example (generate image thumbnail when one is uploaded). This example was adapter from a previous version of the API.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

exports.generateThumbs = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {

    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucket = await storage.bucket(object.name);

    const filePath = object.name;
    const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
    const bucketDir = path.dirname(filePath);

    const workingDir = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'thumbs');
    const tmpFilePath = path.join(workingDir, 'source.png');

    if (fileName.includes('thumb@') || !object.contentType.includes('image')) {
      console.log('exiting function');
      return false;
    }

    // 1. Ensure thumbnail dir exists
    await fs.ensureDir(workingDir);

    // 2. Download Source File
    const file = await bucket.file(filePath);

    await file.download({
      destination: tmpFilePath
    });

    // 3. Resize the images and define an array of upload promises
    const sizes = [64, 128, 256];

    const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
      const thumbName = `thumb@${size}_${fileName}`;
      const thumbPath = path.join(workingDir, thumbName);

      // Resize source image
      await sharp(tmpFilePath)
        .resize(size, size)
        .toFile(thumbPath);

      // Upload to GCS
      return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
        destination: path.join(bucketDir, thumbName)
      });
    });

    // 4. Run the upload operations
    await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    // 5. Cleanup remove the tmp/thumbs from the filesystem
    return fs.remove(workingDir);
  });
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Not Found
    at new ApiError (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:58:28)
    at Util.parseHttpRespMessage (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:159:41)
    at Util.handleResp (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:136:74)
    at Duplexify.requestStream.on.on.res (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js:392:31)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Duplexify.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at onResponse (/srv/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:194:19)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:149:11)
```

at  bucket.file(...).download()

API 2.X.X introduced some changes and I can't seem to make this work. Can anyone give me a hand?
Thank you.

Comment: FYI `bucket.file()` doesn't return a promise, so there's no need to use `await` here.  It just returns the File object directly.  Anyway, the error message looks to me like the file you're trying to download isn't found.

Comment: Thank you for the file comment improvement. Indeed that's the error but the filepath is correct. Here is the log: { filePath: 'images/profiles/image_test.jpg',
  fileName: 'image_test.jpg',
  bucketDir: 'images/profiles',
  workingDir: '/tmp/thumbs',
  tmpFilePath: '/tmp/thumbs/source.png' }

Answer (score 2):

Got it working with the following code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

exports.generateThumbs = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucket = storage.bucket(object.bucket);
    const filePath = object.name;
    const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
    const bucketDir = path.dirname(filePath);

    const workingDir = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'thumbs');
    const tmpFilePath = path.join(workingDir, 'source.png');

    if (fileName.includes('thumb@') || !object.contentType.includes('image')) {
      console.log('exiting function');
      return false;
    }

    // 1. Ensure thumbnail dir exists
    await fs.ensureDir(workingDir);

    // 2. Download Source File
    await  bucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tmpFilePath
    });

    // 3. Resize the images and define an array of upload promises
    const sizes = [64, 128, 256];

    const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
      const thumbName = `thumb@${size}_${fileName}`;
      const thumbPath = path.join(workingDir, thumbName);

      // Resize source image
      await sharp(tmpFilePath)
        .resize(size, size)
        .toFile(thumbPath);

      // Upload to GCS
      return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
        destination: path.join(bucketDir, thumbName)
      });
    });

    // 4. Run the upload operations
    await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    // 5. Cleanup remove the tmp/thumbs from the filesystem
    return fs.remove(workingDir);
  });
```